# How to prevent Google Chrome from saving extension command history

Tags: javascript, facebook, github, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension for Google Chrome that processes omnibox commands and loads facebook pages according to those commands.

During testing, I find Chrome to be saving history of these commands. How might I prevent Chrome from saving this command history?

Chrome version: Version 25.0.1323.1 dev

Source code for app at [Github](http://www.github.com/srcreigh/fbplus)

Chrome web store install [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fb+/fblalmpmmhnomnfdjeeodnpopfehdmdl)